# Zooming in/out responsive case

Tags: css

For example, I have a button. I can set width and height in two ways:

```
<button></button>
```

Option 1:

```
width:30px;
height:30px;
```

Option 2:

```
width:10vw;
height:10vh;
```

If I zoom option 1 - the element will be actually bigger or smaller than what I set.
If I zoom option 2- nothing will change, it permanent.

On this website, at least it looks like only the "camera" zooming in and the size of the element won't change. Just like I look closer but nothing really changing. Please look at the button "get started" for example.
https://www.wix.com/

How to can I set the button (or any other element) as the way this website did? (effect of camera zooming without change the element size)

Thanks for your help !

Edit:

Left top button in the corner set with px both height and width.
https://i.imagesup.co/images2/daa9de845d2e0a90c9a224e7326127a4e5df195b.png

zoom 200%:
https://i.imagesup.co/images2/1ea4e157249ded7413e6f00e98da3ef7bccd94fb.png

It's litterly become bigger

Comment: @chazsolo I just edited.

Comment: vw and vh are viewport relative units - so zoom doesn't have an affect on them (but resizing the window would). Can you not use these? Can you give an example of your work and what problems you're facing?

Comment: Yes, I added screenshots in the question (under Edit). @chazsolo

Comment: [It's pretty much pointless to try and detect zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers), and impossible with only CSS. If you don't want the buttons to change size despite page zoom, you should stick with using `vw`/`vh`